# Automake error building library - Phantom file

Tags: autotools, automake, libtool

I'm adding autotools features to a personal library but I have some problems. I precise that autotools are totally new for me.

```
.
|-- Makefile.am
|-- configure.ac
`-- socket++
    |-- Makefile.am
    |-- base_socket.cpp
    |-- base_socket.hpp
    |-- client.cpp
    |-- client.hpp
    |-- config.h
    |-- config.h.in
    |-- refcount++.hpp
    |-- server.cpp
    |-- server.hpp
    |-- server.imp.hpp
    `-- types
        |-- Makefile.am
        |-- simple_socket.cpp
        |-- simple_socket.hpp
        |-- simple_socket_stop.cpp
        |-- simple_socket_stop.hpp
        |-- text_buffered.hpp
        `-- text_buffered.imp.hpp
```

Here is `configure.ac`

```
AC_INIT([socket++], [1.2], [xcodexif@xif.fr], [socket++], [http://dev.xif.fr/socketxx])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([socket++/config.h])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([socket++/base_socket.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile socket++/Makefile socket++/types/Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

# Distribute additional compiler and linker flags
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([AM_LDFLAGS])

# Checks for compilers
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11

# Libtool
LT_INIT
LT_LANG([C++])

# Checks for header files
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([arpa/inet.h inttypes.h netdb.h netinet/in.h stddef.h sys/ioctl.h sys/socket.h unistd.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_SSIZE_T

# Checks for library functions
AC_FUNC_ERROR_AT_LINE
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gethostbyname inet_ntoa select socket strerror])

AC_OUTPUT
```

Here is `socket++/Makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
AM_CXXFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/socket++ @AM_CXXFLAGS@
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

SUBDIRS = types

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsocket++.la
library_includedir=$(includedir)/socket++
library_include_HEADERS = refcount++.hpp base_socket.hpp client.hpp server.imp.hpp server.hpp
libsocket++_la_SOURCES = base_socket.cpp client.cpp server.cpp
socket++_libincludedir = $(libdir)/socket++/include
nodist_socket++_libinclude_HEADERS = config.h
libsocket++_la_LIBADD = types/libsocket++types.a
```

And finally `socket++/types/Makefile.am`

```
noinst_lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsocket++types.la
library_includedir=$(includedir)/socket++/types
library_include_HEADERS = simple_socket_stop.hpp simple_socket.hpp text_buffered.imp.hpp text_buffered.hpp
libsocket++types_la_SOURCES = simple_socket_stop.cpp simple_socket.cpp
```

All is fine with `./configure`
But when I `make`, I have this error :

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/socket++/socket++/types'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'libsocket++types.c', needed by 'libsocket++types.lo'.  Stop.
```

That's strange because `libsocket++types.c`was never defined in `libsocket++types_la_SOURCES`

I searched for a while but found nothing about phantoms file like this.
Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a few issues with the use of `<prefix>_` primaries:

`lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsocket++.la` results in a [derived variable name](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Canonicalization) of `libsocket__`

```
libsocket___includedir = $(includedir)/socket++
libsocket___include_HEADERS = ...
libsocket___la_SOURCES = ...
```

You can put header files in the `_SOURCES` list as well. i.e., if a header is changed, `make` will see that the library, or other dependents, must be recompiled.

What you've called a 'phantom' target, is typically referred to as a [convenience library](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Libtool-Convenience-Libraries), where: `libsocket++types.la` transforms to the `libsocket__types_` prefix. The parent `Makefile.am` should add include paths to `AM_CPPFLAGS`. Since `subdirs` will be descended first, you can add the convenience library with:

```
libsocket___la_LIBADD = types/libsocket++types.la
```

---

Also, it's `noinst_LTLIBRARIES` *not* `noinst_lib_LTLIBRARIES`.

Comment: I thought that it was a '+' character-related problem. It was right. And I called 'phantom' file `libsocket++types.c` because it did't exists. Thanks for help